# Separate fuction for each button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Trying to create a python program in tkinter to mark attendance of persons engaged in a special duty. By clicking the button containing their name the figure right to their name is incremented by 1. While i created the function when any button is placed all figures are got incremented. And the attempt finally reached here.

```
from tkinter import *
staff=['GEORGE ', 'JAMES ', 'THOMAS', 'MATHEW',
       'CLETUSCRUZ', 'FREDY', 'PAUL', 'MEGANI', 'BILL',
       'JULIA ']


def factory(number):
   def f():
        number.set(number.get()+1)
   return f    
functions =[]
for i in range(10):
    functions.append(factory(i))
for i in functions:
    f()
window = Tk()
window.title(" Duty List")
window.geometry('320x900')
number = IntVar()


row_value =3
for i in staff:
    ibutton = Button(window, text= i, command=clicked)
    ibutton.grid(column=1, row=row_value)
    ilabel = Label(window, textvariable=number)
    ilabel.grid(column=2,row=row_value)
    
    row_value+=1
window.mainloop()`
```

Comment: I couldn't get your factory function working so I took a different approach. Seems to work ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory now creates a unique `IntVar` for each individual.

`link` connects button press to `onclick` for processing `IntVar`

I've used `columnconfigure` to push the numbers to the right hand side of `window`

```py
import tkinter as tk

staff=["GEORGE ", "JAMES ", "THOMAS", "MATHEW",
       "CLETUSCRUZ", "FREDY", "PAUL", "MEGANI", "BILL",
       "JULIA "]

window = tk.Tk()
window.title(" Duty List")
window.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)

def factory(n):
    return tk.IntVar(value = n)

def onclick(a):
    b = a.get()+1
    a.set(b)

def link(a, b):
    return lambda: a(b)
    
for i,n in enumerate(staff):
    b = factory(0)
    a = tk.Button(window, text= n, bd = 1)
    a.grid(column = 0, row = i, sticky = tk.NW, padx = 4, pady = 4)
    a["command"] = link(onclick, b)

    l = tk.Label(window, text = "", textvariable = b, anchor = tk.NW)
    l.grid(column = 1, row = i, sticky = tk.NE, padx = 4, pady = 4)

window.geometry("200x319")
window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()
```